# Auto incremento em R

Tags: r

Como faço para gerar um campo ID auto incremental (1,2,3...) em um data.frame em R que em uma nova coluna?

```
meuDataFrase<- as_tibble(unique(tabelImportada$ColunaX))
```

Preciso criar uma nova coluna nesse data.frame que tenha os números da linha porque vou gravar essa informação em uma tabela dimensional no postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso é usar a função `rownames_to_column()` do pacote [tibble](/questions/tagged/tibble).

O exemplo abaixo inclui ids para as linhas da tabela `iris`. Nesse caso ele cria uma coluna chamada "rowname".

```
library(tidyverse)
# só para imprimir melhor
tbl_iris <- as_tibble(iris)

tbl_iris %>% 
     rownames_to_column()
# A tibble: 150 x 6
   rowname Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
   <chr>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>  
 1 1                5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 2 2                4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa 
 3 3                4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa 
 4 4                4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 5 5                5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa 
 6 6                5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa 
 7 7                4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa 
 8 8                5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa 
 9 9                4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa 
10 10               4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa 
# … with 140 more rows
```

Outra alterativa é criar uma coluna com o nome que você quiser usando `mutate()` do [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) combinado com `seq_len()`.

```
tbl_iris %>% 
  mutate(id = seq_len(nrow(.)))
# A tibble: 150 x 6
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    id
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <int>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      1
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa      2
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      3
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa      4
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa      5
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa      6
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa      7
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa      8
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa      9
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa     10
# … with 140 more rows
```

Comment: É melhor vc usar a função row_number()

Answer (score 2):

Lembre-se sempre de trazer um exemplo reproduzível. Criei um `DF` simples como exemplo, mas o conceito é o mesmo para outros `DF's`.

Código:

```
x <- data.frame(z = c(51:101), y = c(50:100))

for(i in 1:nrow(x)) {
    
    x[i,3] <- i
    
}
```

Caso suas `rownames` não forem números, utilize o seguinte comando antes:

```
rownames(x) <- NULL
```

Obs.: Coloquei a coluna `3` no `for()`, mas você deve colocar o número da coluna que você deseja que apareça o número da linha.